# IQueryable concat causes order to be ignored

Tags: c#, linq

I have two ordered `IQueryable`:

```
var stickyMessages = GetStickyMessages(binUser, filterModel, messages);
var nonSticky = GetNonStickyMessages(binUser, messages);
```

What I would like to do is combine those into one `IQueryable`, keeping the original order from both intact.

Problem is that if I use `Concat` like so, then the order is ignored somehow:

```
var messagesCombined = stickyMessages.Concat(stickyMessages);
return messagesCombined;
```

If I simple return `nonSticky` or `stickMessages`, the order is maintained. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Because after concatting two enumerables the result is not in order anyways, which is why most IQueryable "translators" are ignoring ordering before concatting. You have to restate the ordering AFTER concatting them.

See also [Order by does not work with Concat() in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984001/order-by-does-not-work-with-concat-in-linq)